# Different between bitwise left shift of Int32 and Int64

Tags: c#, binary

[image]

Code:

```
var test1 = 1 & Int64.Parse("1") << 32; // 0
var test2 = 1 & Int32.Parse("1") << 32; // 1 <= It should be 0
```

Hello , Can some one help me to understand the result of above image. Why the result is different.
Do we have any tutorial for this.
[image]

Comment: Try `1 & Int64.Parse("1") << 64;`. It also results in 1. I'm pretty sure it's overflow.

Comment: Since it was only two lines, I've added your code as text, OP. Please always add code as text (with an image for illustrative purposes if necessary) otherwise we can't debug it.

Comment: What result do you expect and why? I see in comments you want `1` as LSB for 64 bits? What happens with 64 bits if you shift `1` to the left 32 times and then mask LSB?

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators) is "tutorial".

Comment: `/* 1  after shift 32 bit = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 * 32 bit/`
            `// operator & with 1`
                                `/* 1 = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 * 32 bit/`
I expected the result should be 0. Because 1 after move to left 32 bit , it become 0.

Answer (score 4):

[Lower down the same page that @KekuSemau references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#shift-count-of-the-shift-operators)

> **Shift count of the shift operators**
>
> For the shift operators `<<` and `>>`, the type of the right-hand operand must be int or a type that has a predefined implicit numeric conversion to int.
>
> For the `x << count` and `x >> count` expressions, the actual shift count depends on the type of x as follows:
>
> - If the type of `x` is `int` or `uint`, the shift count is defined by the low-order five bits of the right-hand operand. That is, the shift count is computed from `count & 0x1F` (or `count & 0b_1_1111`).
> - If the type of `x` is `long` or `ulong`, the shift count is defined by the low-order six bits of the right-hand operand. That is, the shift count is computed from `count & 0x3F` (or `count & 0b_11_1111`).

In other words, any shift higher than the number of bits in the value are simply discarded.

This is mirrored in [ECMA-334 Part 12.10](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_5th_edition_december_2017.pdf), the C# spec, which also adds:

> If the resulting shift count is zero, the shift operators simply return the value of `x`.
>
> Shift operations never cause overflows and produce the same results in checked and unchecked contexts.

Answer (score 3):

From [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators):
`The left-shift operation discards the high-order bits that are outside the range of the result type and sets the low-order empty bit positions to zero`

Overflowing bits are *not* placed back at the other side.
Going by that, for Int32, any lshift >= 32 should result in 0, which is not the case.

It seems that `<<n` is performed as `<< (n % bitsize)`.
That means for Int32:
<< 32 = no change at all
<< 33 equals << 1    (33 % 32 = 1)
<< 66 equals << 2    (66 % 32 = 2)

Looking at the IL in Linqpad, i can see for `<< 66`
`IL_0008:  ldc.i4.2`
`IL_0009:  shl`
... that it performs directly `<<2`